# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in Chrome and FireFox, but headers are ok

Tags: http, header, cors

Both Chrome as well as Firefox are suddenly nagging me about the same origin policy and fail to display the correct font for a part of my site. (Because I use subdomains, long story) Of course there are ways to circumvent this problem altogether, but I'm keen on solving this issue, so it won't pop up with some different thing later in the future.

FF: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource
Chr: has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy

And all that.
The thing is: when I do a GET via curl or even just an in browser tool the headers are fine!

Last-Modified: Sat, 18 May 2013 09:18:21 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
CF-Cache-Status: HIT

As you can see I'm using Cloudflare, doing a direct request to my server as well as going via CF both give the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' nicely.

Any other thing that might be bugging me here? 
I really can't think of anything to try at this point.

Comment: Problem seemed to have solved itself, or to be precise: after re-uploading everything the problem disappeared. Seems like some other header info was corrupted, thus causing browsers to display this error in, eh, error. (And acting accordingly, thus not displaying the font.)

Confusing error-messages...